# ip over bluetooth / bluez5

Tags: ip, bluez

For several hours I've been searching for shell commands to establish an IP link between two devices via Bluetooth/bluez5. Up to bluez4 there was `pand` which isn't available anymore.

Most of the documentation and howtos around address bluez4 and hence are outdated. In the packet `bluez-tests` I found `test-nap` that returns `Server for nap registered`, however I cannot find a new network device when I call `ip addr`.
In addition I haven't found how to connect from the other device to that newly created server.

Could you give me some hints on

- how to connect from a bluez5 device to a remote NAP server?
- how to create network device from the NAP connection?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found out that I missed the package bluez-tools which contains tools such as bt-network. This can be used to create a server on one side and a client on the other side. That tool talks to the bluez stack via dbus messages, which 'magically' creates the network devices (eg. br0 and bnep0) when the connection is established.

Actually in my case one of the devices doesn't seem to support network protocol on its bluez stack, which seems to be related to a missing bnep kernel module. However this seems to be a side issue to my original question.